# Simple jQuery AJAX quick search adding "_" which does not show in HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple live search working with jQuery and PHP, however it keeps adding an underscore to each result, as shown.

I have tried simple techniques to remove the underscores but have had no luck.

[image: How results show]

[image: HTML]

Javascript:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    search_with_ajax();
  });
  $("#search_term").keyup(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    search_with_ajax();

  });
});

  function search_with_ajax() {
$.ajaxSetup ({
// Disable caching of AJAX responses
cache: false
});

$.ajax( {
  url: "qsearch.php",
  cache: false,

  data: {search_term: $("#search_term").val()},
  success: function(data) {
    $(".qsearchbox").html(data);
  }
})
  }
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['search_term'])){
  $shortened_term = substr($_REQUEST['search_term'],0, 20);    
  $stripped_term = strip_tags($shortened_term);              
  $safe_term = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $stripped_term); /injection attack
  if($safe_term != "") {
$query = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE make like '$safe_term%' OR model like '$safe_term%' OR colour like '$safe_term%'" ;
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query)
  or die("Error in query: '$query'");

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $return_string .= "<a class='searchrow' href='index.php?car=".$row['carIndex']."'><div class='swi'>".$row['make'];
    $return_string .= "</div> <div class='swi'>".$row['model']."</div> ";
    $return_string .= "<div class='swi'> ";
    $return_string .= $row['colour'];
    $return_string .= "</div> ";
    $return_string .= "<div class='swi'> " . $row['Reg'] . "</div> ";
    $return_string .= "</div></a> ";



  }
}else{
  $return_string = "No matches found!";
}
  }
}
echo $return_string;
?>
```

SWI CSS:

```
width: 23%;
margin: 0px;
display: inline-block;
```

The underscore does not show if logged on the console

Console Snippet:

```
<a class='searchrow' href='index.php?car=102'>
<div class='swi'>BMW</div> <div
class='swi'>321</div> <div class='swi'> red
</div> <div class='swi'> D</div> </div>
```

(goes on for every result)

Comment: whats the code for class swi?

Comment: well thats all weird to me, can you post the page location?

Comment: does the _ come out directly from the query itself if you print that data out before the injection? If not, then do you see it if you try to console.log() the output before you inject it into the HTML?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "location"?

Comment: URL of the site, if its online

Comment: This site is not live, I have it running on XAMPP on Windows and MAMP on OSX

Comment: I just added the example from a console log, it does not show an underscore.

Comment: older browsers use to do this with some particular html, but i don't recall the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `preg_replace('/^(_|\s)/', '', $row['model']);` and the like, if it's a database thing. Othewise, change:

```
$return_string .= "<a class='searchrow' href='index.php?car=".$row['carIndex']."'><div class='swi'>".$row['make'];
$return_string .= "</div> <div class='swi'>".$row['model']."</div> ";
$return_string .= "<div class='swi'> ";
$return_string .= $row['colour'];
$return_string .= "</div> ";
$return_string .= "<div class='swi'> " . $row['Reg'] . "</div> ";
$return_string .= "</div></a> ";
```

to something more like:

```
$return_string = "<a class='searchrow' href='index.php?car="{$row['carIndex']}'>".
"<div class='swi'>{$row['make']}</div>".
"<div class='swi'>{$row['model']}</div>".
"<div class='swi'>{$row['colour']}</div>".
"<div class='swi'>{$row['Reg']}</div>".
'</a>';
```

The above shows a better technique. I believe you also have an extra `</div>` in there, before your closing `</a>`. Personally, I prefer Object Oriented PHP, using `$database_connection->fetch_object()`, then it's `$row->$make` and the like. If inserting into double quotes then curly braces may be easier than concatenation.

Comment: I have tried str_replace and it didn't work I doubt it's server side as it doesn't show in the console.

Comment: If your browser is doing it take out the white space.

Comment: No, that's PHP. I see white space in your console. But wait, some of your HTML that you created with PHP has a white space "<div class='swi'>(right here)". Probably, just take that out, if your Server is not returning the white space or underscore.